# Wiremock.net not responding in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, wiremock

I have been playing a little with Wiremock.net for mocking out HTTP calls. I've got it working happily running from a console application, but when I try to do it with a unit test it stops responding. Here is my complete code:

```
FluentMockServer serviceMock;

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    serviceMock = FluentMockServer.Start(new FluentMockServerSettings { Urls = new[] { "http://+:5010" } });
    serviceMock.Given(Request.Create().UsingPost().WithPath("/callbacks/booked"))
        .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithStatusCode(200).WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .WithBodyAsJson(new List<Callback>
            {
                new Callback { CustomerId = 1, RequestedFor = new DateTime(2017, 12, 14, 15, 00, 01) },
            }));
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanHitMockEndpoint()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:5010");
    var response = client.Get<List<Callback>>(new RestRequest("/callbacks/booked"));

    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup() => serviceMock.Stop();
```

When I get the response back, it has a status code of zero, and the message "Unable to connect to the remote server"

The strange thing is, if I move the Initialize and Cleanup items into a console app, and run it alongside, the test will work. I've confirmed that the Initialize/Cleanup is running, so I'm definitely either missing something obvious, or something strange is going on!

Any help would be great.

Comment: I know this an old question, but for future reference, most likely the ports that you are specifying are already in use, in that case wiremock will use a different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not totally sure what the issue is here, but I've narrowed it down to the handling of the ports. I've modified the server creation to:

```
serviceMock = FluentMockServer.Start();
```

And used the IP it wires to internally for my service setup:

```
var client = new RestClient(serviceMock.Urls.First());
```

This then works without problems.